# remove borders inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, border, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm trying to put multiple JLists in a JPanel and the JPanel in a JScrollPane. The problem is that when I add the JScrollPane to the equation there is a space between the JList and outer border, how do I get rid of this border so it's fills horizontally?

Here is a small sample code that demonstrates this problem with a JLabel instead of JList.

**/edit: It's seems to be windows thing, it runs fine on Mac OS.**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Test test = new Test();
    }

    public Test()
    {
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        this.setContentPane(contentPane);        
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(createLeftPane());
        sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow));
        this.add(sp, BorderLayout.WEST);

        LookAndFeel.installBorder(sp, "BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()");        

        StackTraceElement[] st = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        for(int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(st[i]);
        }

        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    private JPanel createLeftPane()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("TEST LABEL");
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
        panel.add(label, c);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));

        return panel;
    }        
}
```

Here's a screenshot (first one is without the scrollpane)
[image: JScrollPane Problems]

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1479) 
test.Test.<init>(Test.java:27) 
test.Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

**/edit: After some trial and error I found out that when I add a c.weightx = 0.5 to the contrains it does fill Horizontally, but when the scrollPane becomes larger than it's content it makes itself wider, which is weird. See the screenshots below:**

[image]

Comment: +1 for posting SSCCE. Could you please add a screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't because of the scrollpane. Its because you add the label to a JPanel. By default a panel uses a FlowLayot which has has a vertical/horizontal gap of 5 pixels around each component.

Change the FlowLayout to use a 0 gap, or use a different layout. Maybe a BoxLayout.

Comment: what do you mean by "on both directions"? btw I found something interesting, the problem doesn't occur when I run it on my Mac. So apparently it's a windows thing

Comment: @Jesse are you meaning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242341/jcombobox-change-drop-down-popup (JList for JComboBox )

Answer (score 3):

`component.setBorder(null)` removes any border which has been set on the component

Comment: Great answer! I've looking solution of this problem a very long time, and this simple solution works!. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem doesn't occur when I run it on my Mac, so apparently it's a Windows thing.

In addition to the expected UI defaults for `background`, `foreground`, `font` and `opaque`, [`BasicPanelUI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicPanelUI.html) installs a border, while `com.apple.laf.AquaPanelUI` (apparently) does not.

```
LookAndFeel.installBorder(p,"Panel.border");
```

You might try setting yours to `null`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried setting it to null like this:
LookAndFeel.installBorder(sp, null);
But it throws a nullPointerException at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:334) (sp is my JScrollPane)

Comment: Edit your answer to include your revised [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and stack trace. An empty border by be required, e.g. `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()`.

Comment: I revised my SSCCE and included a stack track. I had to look up how to use a stack trace so I hope I did it the right way. The `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()` did not work, but again I'm not sure I did it the right way.

Comment: Try setting it on your `contentPane`, rather than on your `sp`. I'm on Mac OS X, too.

Comment: I used this syntax: `LookAndFeel.installBorder(contentPane, "BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()");` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I guessing more like this: `LookAndFeel.installBorder(contentPane, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());`.

Comment: That won't work, the `installBorder()` method requires a String

Comment: D'oh, you're right; maybe `contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());`.

Comment: nope, that's not it, I already tried setting all the borders to empty.

Comment: Did you try `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout`? I'm on  on Mac OS X.

Comment: Yes I have, `BoxLayout` presented the same problem. `GridLayout` worked well, but isn't flexible enough because it doesn't allow different shaped cells. I did find something interesting, when I use `c.weightx = 0.5` (c is a `GridBagContraint`) it does fill horizontally, but when the scrollpanes height is larger than it's content it grows wider than it's supposed to. I'll add some screenshots to show it.

Answer (score 1):

are you meaning this way ???

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class FilesInTheJList {

    private static final int COLUMNS = 5;
    private Dimension size;

    public FilesInTheJList() {
        final JList list = new JList(new File("C:\\").listFiles()) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                if (size != null) {
                    return new Dimension(size);
                }
                return super.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
            }
        };
        list.setFixedCellHeight(50);
        list.setFixedCellWidth(150);
        size = list.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
        size.width *= COLUMNS;
        list.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
        list.setVisibleRowCount(0);
        list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Files In the JList");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                FilesInTheJList fITJL = new FilesInTheJList();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class MyCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            if (value instanceof File) {
                File file = (File) value;
                setText(file.getName());
                setIcon(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file));
                if (isSelected) {
                    setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                    setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
                } else {
                    setBackground(list.getBackground());
                    setForeground(list.getForeground());
                }
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 25));
                setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
                setFont(list.getFont());
                setOpaque(true);
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

.

.

similair but better way by @trashgod [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620579/individual-and-not-continuous-jtables-cell-selection/7620726#7620726)

Comment: and code line `f.add(new JScrollPane(list));` isn't correct definitions for JScrollPane, is there another way how I must define that :-)

Comment: sorry, my search didn't find it, my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of trashgod worked for me with

```
LookAndFeel.installBorder(scrollpane,BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the `JScrollPane`'s border using

```
JScrollPane yourScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
yourScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```