# How to detect the widest protoTypeValue for a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox, layout-manager

I have a JComboBox which is dynamically filled with values. The values can change over time and I need the JComboBox to be wide enough to fit any value that eventually might get inserted.

I know the set of possible values which are localized Strings. A multi-item variant of the [`setPrototypeDisplayValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setPrototypeDisplayValue%28E%29) method is what I actually need, but it doesn't exist. That variant would then take the item that makes the JComboBox the widest.

How can I have a JComboBox appear as wide as needed to have all items in a predetermined set fit inside the combobox, even when some of these items will only be added to the combo box after it has been displayed?

Comment: that's default behaviour - provided the combo is contained in a parent with a LayoutManager that always sizes the comp to its prefSize, as does f.i. FlowLayout

Comment: and depends of if you really want to play with  [PrototypeDisplayValue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679421/why-jcombobox-ignore-prototypedisplayvalue) or [with size for BasicComboBoxPopup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242341/jcombobox-change-drop-down-popup)